# How to use jQuery in a Grunt task

Tags: jquery, node.js, gruntjs

I am copying some HTML files in a Grunt task, and would like to operate on then using jQuery - something like this. . .

```
 copy: {
    expand: true,
    src: 'source/*.html',
    dest: 'build/',
    ext: '.html',
    filter: 'isFile',
    options: {
      process: function (content, srcpath) {
        // find all occurrences of <span class='foo'> in file and wrap in a <div class='bah'>
        $('span.foo').wrap('<div class="bah"></div>');
      }
    }
```

I see there is a grunt plugin [grunt-jsdom-jquery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-jsdom-jquery) that seems to address this, but it was last committed to 2 years ago, and I cannot get it to work - it seems overly complex anyway.

I'm thinking that I need to use [node jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) some how (and certainly the documentation has an example that loads jQuery as a script), but how can I apply this in Grunt, and specifically in one of the main tasks like copy or concat?

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't [`cheerio`](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) be enough, or do you really need a full "browser" environment (jsdom)?

Comment: @mscdex Thanks for the cheerio tip off.  I see there is a grunt wrapper for it - grunt-dom-massager :)  Will give it a go.

Comment: @mscdex Back from holiday and have just tried that dom-massager - it works fantastically well.  So quick and simple.  Thanks again for the cheerio tip off.

Answer (score 0):

Try [grunt-processhtml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-processhtml)

There is a [method to change blocks of content](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-processhtml#optionscustomblocktypes) where you can add an array of custom block types:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (processor) {
  // This will allow to use this <!-- build:customBlock[:target] <value> --> syntax 
  processor.registerBlockType('customBlock', function (content, block, blockLine, blockContent) {
    var title = '<h1>' + block.asset + '</h1>';
    var result = content.replace(blockLine, title);

    return result;
  });
};
```

Which will change the following in your html:

```
<!-- build:customBlock myValue -->
<p>This will be replaced with the result of the custom block above</p>
<!-- /build -->
```

The result will be

```
<h1>myValue</h1>
```